# filter messages in logstash with different index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am getting 3 types of messages in logstash, based on that i need to parse and save in elasticSearch with 3 different index

Message 1 => "2021-05-26T09:55:36.091040+00:00 10.13.14.11 [S=294230650] [ID=fbf282:30:11158988]  !!! Repeated 38332 times"

Message 2 => "2021-06-10T09:57:02.237521+00:00 10.13.14.11 [S=21473] |START     |ABC       |1aa9d286a960501696a33c107b71f21b"

Message 3 => "2021-05-26T10:51:04.139725+00:00 10.10.15.11 [2021-05-26 10:56:05,308] 4066 0002 com.sonus.sbc.sip INFO (TransportLayer.cpp:1073) - DataReadCB: Received

I tried with below logstash configuration, as all messages getting parsed with gork filters but getting stored in "default-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" index.

Expected Result :-messages should get stored in respective index using  "msgType" field.

```
input {
        beats {
                port => 5044
        }
}

filter {
     if "[S=" in [message] and  "[ID=" in [message]{
      grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{IP:IP}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:SeqNo}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:ID}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
            add_field => {
                "msgType" => "message1"
            }
        }
    }
    else if "[S=" in [message]{
      grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{IP:IP}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:SeqNo}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
            add_field => {
                "msgType" => "message2"
            }
        }
    } else {
      grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{IP:IP}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:anotherDate}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:messageBody}" }
            add_field => {
                "msgType" => "message3"
            }
        }
    }
}

output {
 if [msgType] == "message1" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "10.133.11.23:9200"
      user => "elastic"
      password => "changeme"
      ecs_compatibility => disabled
      index => "message1-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
  }
  else if [msgType] == "message2" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "10.133.11.23:9200"
      user => "elastic"
      password => "changeme"
      ecs_compatibility => disabled
      index => "message2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
  }
  else if [msgType] == "message3" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "10.133.11.23:9200"
      user => "elastic"
      password => "changeme"
      ecs_compatibility => disabled
      index => "message3-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
  }
  else {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "10.133.11.23:9200"
      user => "elastic"
      password => "changeme"
      ecs_compatibility => disabled
      index => "default-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what is not working. What is the expected result and what is the result you are getting?

Comment: @leandrojmp..updated my question

Comment: your filter logic correct. I am doubting the "msgType" is being attached to "message" document or something similar. Can you just do `stdout {
     codec => rubydebug
   }` and comment out `elastic` output to see where that `msgType` is being attached?

Comment: Can't replicate, just ran your pipeline with your example messages and sending the output to different files instead of elasticsearch and the logic worked as expected. Can you share an example of a message the went to the index default?

Comment: yep I could not replicate either. Code seems to be fine to me

Comment: Its strange, Just restarted all services and its working fine!! Thank you @leandrojmp, JBone

Comment: Is there any other efficient solution.

Comment: over `restarting`? that seems to be the best solution so far.